# VS Code Breakpoint circles stopped showing in left margin

Tags: visual-studio-code

For some reason breakpoints have stopped showing in the left margin. Toggling breakpoints still work - and if you hover up and down the left margin the little circle follows you up and down.  The breakpoint is also listed in the breakpoints area - but I can't see visually any breakpoints in the file.

this is a pain - I can't think of what I would have done.  ( I am debugging node.js )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be because of an extension. I had the same problem, and I disabled the "One Dark Pro" theme extension, and now breakpoints are showing.